# IIS Express stopping all Basic Auth

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, iis, asp.net-web-api

The project I'm working on uses C# WebAPI 2, and used to use Windows Active Directory authentication for everything. We're attempting to transition to Basic auth using a `AuthorizationFilterAttribute`, but IIS Express is making that quite difficult. Originally any request with Basic auth with get a `401.2` response because Basic auth wasn't enabled. To fix this I added:

```
<basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
```

to **applicationhost.config**. Now all requests with a Basic auth header get a `401.1` error, as if IIS Express tries to authenticate the request itself, without going through the attribute.

I created a blank project and attempted the same set up, and it worked fine! I compared **applicationhost.config**, **web.config**, and **Global.asax.cs** of the two projects, and everything appears to be the same. So I can't figure out why IIS Express isn't cooperating for the initial project.

What other files / config settings should I look at to get this resolved?

Comment: IIS Express with basic authentication enabled of course uses its own module to perform basic authentication. Why do you think that should go through your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to look in App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs . If it's using OWIN, you'll need to add the basic auth module to the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the authentication mode to make sure it's not set to 'Windows'?

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
```